# Frame stutters appear just when touching/swiping the screen on Android EMUI 8

Tags: huawei, 8.0-oreo, performance, bugs, lagging

I have heard about intensive apps causing frame stutters on Android, but this isn't apparently. I'm using a Huawei P10 Lite with Android EMUI 8 (Oreo), and the stutters in this case only happen when I touch/swipe on the screen. For example, if I swipe fast and then release my finger, the screen momentum effect on android just works fine, as it is 60fps, but when I physically touch the screen, doesn't matter the number of fingers I have on it, it just stutters, like if the framerate dropped to about 20 or 30 fps idk. However, I tried installing one of those control center dropdown menus for android, specifically the "Mi Control Center: Notifications and Quick Actions" by Treydev Inc; I did it because the dropdown menu was the first thing where I noticed the issue. It didn't work, and it seemed to drain my battery a bit, so I just removed it, and weird enough so did the stutter issue. For a while it seemed to be gone, and I tried rebooting the phone to make it sure, but after booting it back, the problem returned. I don't think it's any of the apps I have installed, as I only use duolingo, termux, duckduckgo and like. The phone isn't rooted, and no launchers or 'customization' apps are being used. If it's a video, android scroll momentum or anything, it just works fine, only when the screen is touched. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I have a P10 lite in the same configuration. I did not experience your problem, instead I experienced another one: the screen in a miniaturized form goes into a corner and is locked. It happens rarely and a screen turn off/turn on solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is quite an old one. I just did factory reset , partially due to the amount of junk files I had, and It worked back again. I still don't know what it is, but if anyone has a solution for those who have the same problem and don't wanna start again, I'll leave this post open to answers.

Comment: Did a factory reset fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, I did (for other reasons too), but as I say, there will be people that wouldn't want to do so just for that, so I am still looking from time to time for an answer. I marked it as solved cause technically it's solved, but I am looking for a better answer. Feel free to post one if you or someone has it!